# How to remove the last comma in an each loop in Wiremock

Tags: json, handlebars.js, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I  need to write a stub for a request that would look something like this:

```
[
    { "todo_id": 1 },
    { "todo_id": 2 }
]
```

The number of todo objects in the request can vary.

My response currently looks like this:

```
"response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body": "[ {{#each (jsonPath request.body '$') as |todo|}}
                   { \"todo_id\": {{todo.todo_id}} },
               {{/each}}
             ]"
}
```

Please note that I spaced out the body to make it more readable, in the actual stub, it is all on one line.

So my problem is that I need the comma after my todo object in case there are more than one object passed in the request. This however leaves the last object with a comma as well, so if the above request was sent, this would be the response:

```
[
    { "todo_id": 1 },
    { "todo_id": 2 },
]
```

This last comma makes `.json()` method fail in Python application that needs to read the responses from this WireMock stub.

Any thoughts on how to get rid of the last comma? I was thinking maybe having an `eq` condition around the comma and checking to see if current `todo` variable is the same as `{{jsonPath request.body '$.[-1]'}}` but writing it like this:

```
{{#eq todo {{jsonPath request.body '$.[-1]'}} }}
```

did not work either.

Any suggestions on how to get rid of the last comma would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got an answer to this on Google Groups.

It is possible to use `@last` within an each loop to detect when you're on the last item e.g:

```
{{#each (jsonPath request.body '$.things') as |thing|}}
  {{#if @last}}
    { "thing": {{{thing}}} }
  {{else}}
    { "thing": {{{thing}}} },
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```